# Twitter reverse auth error

Tags: ios, twitter, ios6, oauth-2.0, iphone-5

NOTE: the code I am using works on iOS 5 perfectly. Nothing has changed.

When going through the motions of the twitter reverse auth, I get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
<error code="89">Error processing your OAuth request: invalid signature or token</error>
</errors>
```

I check to make sure my tokens and other credentials were valid. The only differences here are that I am using an iPhone 5, and/or that I am on iOS 6.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I've exactly the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be iPhone 5 related. Its working on my iPhone 4S with iOS6

Comment: I got it to work. I'm going to post the code I use.

Comment: @nicholjs looking forward to the code!

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out, that on iPhone 5 the TWRequest just is not adding the oauth_token to the authorization header. Hopefully this will be fixed soon...

Update: after deleting my Twitter account from my iPhone it seems to work now. I've also cleared my caches from Safari (maybe this could be a fix as well).

Answer (score 2):

On my iOS 7 device, this happens when the Twitter username/password stored on the phone (accessible from the Settings app) are outdated / incorrect.

I was confused because it was working for some accounts and not others. You will know if the account info is wrong, because it tells you so as soon as you access the account in your Settings app.

Comment: Thanks. This answer saved me a lot of time. Like you said, sometimes account info gets outdated, which you can check by opening the settings app.

Answer (score 0):

**First thing to check**: Make sure your server is not rejecting the token because the length is too long. That was the issue for me. For some reason, the token on the iPhone 5 was longer than the iPhone 4.

**Second thing to check**: Have you registered your twitter app to use reverse auth? You need to get permission.

*Your application's keys have not been enabled for reverse auth privileges*

See the documentation on this. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth
If you do not have permission to use reverse auth, it will not work.

Comment: The code is unchanged code from https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample/? I'm using the same. Another question: how should my server reject the token? This ReverseOAuth implementation is only talking to Twitters server.. Unfortunately I've still error 89 (only on iPhone5) and would be happy to know exactly what you've changed in order to get rid of it :)

Comment: 1.) since some days, ReverseAuth privileges are enabled by default
2.) its working on iPhone 4 device, but not on iPhone 5 device (just as you described on your starting post)
3.) it would be another error, when I would not have permissions